# Regex to match Amazon product URL

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for Regex to match URLs like:

`http://www.amazon.co.uk/Kodak-EasyShare-C195-Digital-Camera/dp/B003VM8Y4I`

To be more specific, product name part (`"Kodak-EasyShare-C195-Digital-Camera"`) could be replaced and product id (`"B003VM8Y4I"`) could also be replaced. But the product id should only consist upper case letter and digital.

Comment: I'm looking for the code you've tried, although I'm not seeing any... hmmm

Comment: Indeed. What part are you missing? Why doesn't it seem to be working?

Comment: Just check the documents of regex, your problem is not so hard to fix. If you try to use uncle google instead of SO for this problem, I bet you already solved it so far.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following regex:

```
\/([A-Z0-9]+)$
```

Here is a sample code output from http://www.pythonregex.com/ :

```
>>> regex = re.compile("\/([A-Z0-9]+)$")
>>> r = regex.search("http://www.amazon.co.uk/Kodak-EasyShare-C195-Digital-Camera/dp/B003VM8Y4I")
>>> r
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xed1f02057a656860>
>>> regex.match(string)
None

# List the groups found
>>> r.groups()
(u'B003VM8Y4I',) # <----------- RESULT
```